# #1064 mysql error - DOUBLE NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, double

I'm trying to create an sql table called 'cartable'. I'm currently using phpmyadmin via MAMP(Mac Version of WAMP).

When I click on the save button this error appears:

```
    SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `cardatabase`.`CARTABLE` (
`ID` VARCHAR( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`SLOTNUMBER` VARCHAR( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`STATUS` ENUM( 1 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`LATITUDE` DECIMAL( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`LONGITUDE` DECIMAL( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`LOCATION` VARCHAR( 40 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`DEVICEID` VARCHAR( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, `LATITUDE` DECIMAL(20) N' at line 1
```

It seems to be a problem with the double data type as when I change it to varchar the table is created. Is there any other way around it? Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where's the double data type?

Comment: wanted to say decimal sorry, however the problem was with enum, i didn't specify the options. sorted it out now :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
`STATUS` ENUM( 1 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
```

An `enum` type is supposed to be a *string* object, not a numeric one.

From [the MySQL doco](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html),

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.
>
> An enumeration value must be a quoted string literal; it may not be an expression, even one that evaluates to a string value.

Answer (score 2):

you have error in enum line, you need to predefine the enum values as below:

`STATUS` ENUM('ravi', 'kotwani') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,

Full query:

CREATE TABLE `cardatabase`.`CARTABLE` (
`ID` VARCHAR( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`SLOTNUMBER` VARCHAR( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`STATUS` ENUM('ravi', 'kotwani') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`LATITUDE` DECIMAL( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`LONGITUDE` DECIMAL( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`LOCATION` VARCHAR( 40 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`DEVICEID` VARCHAR( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;